# PHP switch($p) take the first case if $p == 1

Tags: php, switch-statement

I have this code:

```
$r = do_something($data);
if ($r == 1) 
{
    echo "it is 1";
}

switch ($r) 
{
    case "a":
        print "a";
        break;

    case "b":
        print "b";
        break;

    default:
        print "default";
}
```

With this code the output should be:

```
it is 1
default
```

but the surprise is that the output is:

```
it is 1
a
```

How is this possible?

edit: after some test i see that:

```
$r === true.
```

so the new question is: when the var is true how work the switch?

Comment: Automatic typecasting problem?

Comment: Read this: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php and use `===` to compare in order to avoid this kind of problems

Comment: What does `var_dump( do_something($data) );` output?

Comment: when i run your code it outputs what it needs

Comment: added new info at original question

Comment: The language of the "new question" you've edited in is a bit ambiguous: are you asking how to *make* the `switch` statement work how you wanted, or for an explanation of why it currently does what it does?

Comment: both but second one is what i want know first. I thinked that 1 or true was the same in php but i think is not true now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP's ["type juggling"](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) rules are rather tricky, and occasionally unintuitive and even controversial. There's [a great big table in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) showing what happens when you make comparisons of various sorts, but to explain your particular case:

- You are working with three different types: `$r` is currently `true`, which is a `boolean`; the `if` statement tests against `1`, which is an `integer`; and the `switch` statement tests against `"a"` and `"b"`, which are `string`s.
- When you compare a `boolean` to an `integer`, PHP first converts the `integer` to a `boolean`, using the rule that `0` converts to `false`, and anything else converts to `true`. This has the effect in your case of `$r == 1` evaluating to `true`, but `$r == 42` would *also* evaluate to `true`.
- When you compare a `boolean` to a `string`, a similar thing happens, but here the `string` gets converted according to this rule: an empty `string` is `false`, anything else is `true`. So `$r == "a"` also evaluates to `true` in your example, which is why that branch of the `switch` statement is executed.

To get the result you were hoping for, you need to force the type conversion to happen in a different way. There are a few ways to do this, but the simplest in your case is to cast `$r` to the same type as what you're comparing it against:

- `(int)$r` will give you the `integer` `1` for a value of `true`, and `0` for `false`, so `if ( (int)$r == 1 )` will give the same result, but be clearer that `$r` wasn't actually an `integer` at that point in the code.
- more importantly, `(string)$r` will give you the `string` `"1"`, so `switch( (string)$r )` won't have to do any "type juggling" to compare against strings like `"a"` and `"b"`, and you won't get any surprises there.

Comment: I love this answer.. you explain all i want know.. thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

I think your `do_something($data)` function returns 1 if it does what it suppose to do. I tried this code and it works. Here it is.

```
function do_something($data){
  return 1;
}

$r= do_something('abc');
if ($r == 1) 
{
  echo "it is 1<br />";
}
switch ($r) 
{
   case "a" : print "a"; break;
   case "b" : print "b"; break;
   default : print "default";
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
it is 1 
default
```

Comment: after some test his value is true not 1